# Grails - MySQL query result with a zero index causing GORM runtime exception

Tags: mysql, grails, grails-orm

I'm using an existing DB from an open source application (OSTicket). There are two tables (OstStaff and OstTicket, where staff hasMany Tickets). However, the big problem is OSTicket assigns a default value of zero to OstTicket.staff_id, when the ticket is not yet assigned to an OstStaff.

The issue arises when you search for tickets and GORM thinks that there is a staff with index equal to 0. I can't even check for null, just keep getting this error:

```
No row with the given identifier exists: [com.facilities.model.OstFacStaff#0]. 
Stacktrace follows:
Message: No row with the given identifier exists: [com.facilities.model.OstFacStaff#0]
```

Any suggestion how I can get around this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by just getting the ids, rather than the record, and then removing the zero index.

```
def ticketCriteria = OstFacTicket.createCriteria()
def staffIdsWithTickets = ticketCriteria.list {
    projections {
        distinct("staff.id")  // **INSTEAD of returning staff, get the id**
    }
    between("created", start, end)
}

def zeroIndex = staffIdsWithTickets.indexOf(0)
if (zeroIndex >= 0) {
    staffIdsWithTickets.remove(zeroIndex)
}
```